# Does Spring-data-elasticsearch works with Spring 3.1.2 version?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I would like to use the spring data elastic search capability with spring 3.1.2. Does spring data elastic search works with spring 3.1.2 version.?

Answer (score 0):

Spring elastic search is available under spring data release of 1.1x and 1.3x. Spring Data 1.1x required Java 1.6 or later. Spring Data 1.3x required Java 1.7 or later.

You are relating SpringData elastic search functionality with SpringFramework version. It does all dependent on which java version you are supposed going to using. Please find the detail and supporting link below for your reference.

Spring framework requirment noted below. You can find them under Mininum Requirment section in the [Link](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/)

**Minimum requirements of Spring Framework**
•JDK 6+ for Spring Framework 4.x
•JDK 5+ for Spring Framework 3.x

Spring data elastic search minimun requrirment noted down. You can find them under note section of below [Link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch)

**Minimum requirements for elastic search**

- Spring data elaticsearch until 1.0.0.RELEASE version is on
  elasticsearch 1.1.x library, which uses java 1.6 or later version
- From spring data elasticsearch 1.1.0.RELEASE the version of
  elasticsearch is 1.3.x which is supporting java 1.7 or later

Comment: Thank you for sharing the insight.

Answer (score 0):

Next Time You Require any dependency information just go to ***mvnrepository.com*** and just select the project and its version it will show complete dependency list over there

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-elasticsearch/1.0.0.RELEASE

Now Answer to Your Question.

No Spring Data ElasticSearch does not work with Spring 3.1.2 it Requires Minimum Spring 4.2.5 RELEASE